# Setting port for hokuyo laser range scanner

Tags: ros, roslaunch, hokuyo-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I have written the following launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node
    pkg="mark_pi_navigation"
    type="mark_pi_navigation.py"
    name="mark_pi_navigation"
    respawn="true">
  </node>
  <node
    pkg="hokuyo_node"
    type="hokuyo_node"
    name="hokuyo_node"
    respawn="true">
    <param name="port" value="/dev/ttyACM2"/>
  </node>
  <node
    pkg="razor_imu_9dof"
    type="imu_node.py"
    name="imu_node" >
    <param name="port" value="/dev/ttyUSB0"/>
  </node>
  <node
    pkg="rosserial_python"
    type="serial_node.py"
    name="arduinoLeft"
    respawn="true">
    <param name="port" value="/dev/ttyACM0"/>
  </node>
  <node
    pkg="rosserial_python"
    type="serial_node.py"
    name="arduinoRight"
    respawn="true">
    <param name="port" value="/dev/ttyACM1"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

I am experiencing some issues with setting the right port for the hokuyo LRS. If I change the port to ACM0 (in launch file and physically) it works without problems... However it timeouts when trying to run from a different port.. I'm I writing the parameter wrong?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222070/setting-port-for-hokuyo-laser-range-scanner/) by [Oevli](https://answers.ros.org/users/25151/oevli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2015-12-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-12-09**:
I've opened an issue about your question title not updating correctly: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues/129

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're configuring the port correctly. Are you certain your laser is actually represented by that device node?

Note that /dev/ttyACMx devices are created in the order that devices are plugged in; they're not automatically associated with a particular USB port or physical device.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Oevli](https://answers.ros.org/users/25151/oevli/) on 2015-12-09**:
yes I have used the ls -l /dev/ttyACM* command, and found the port names by unplugging the device.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-12-09**:
Is there another process running which already has that port open? If there are multiple processes reading from a serial port, often only one of them will actually read data from it, and the others get nothing.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-12-09**:
`sudo lsof /dev/ttyACM1` may be able to get a list of processes which have that device open.